# Convert from Objective-C NSArray to swift [[String:String]]?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I want to convert from `NSArray` to swift array `[Dictionary<String:String>]`

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
let someArray = myArray as? [[String:String]]
```

Optional casting is recommended if you want to make sure you don't get any crashes when converting. You can then use it in `if-let` constructions like this:

```
if let dictArray = myArray as? [[String:String]] {
    // do something with the array of dictionaries
}
```

BTW, your initial definition was not correct, there's no such thing as `Dictionary<String:String>`, the correct definition is `Dictionary<String, String>`.

Comment: (`Dictionary<String:String>` was the syntax used in early Swift releases.)

Comment: Hmm... I hope the OP is up-to-date with Swift :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work": did you get a crash, or did the `if` code was not executed? Could you also give some sample of the Objective-C array you are trying to convert?